# MVC - I'm having trouble with displaying images from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to display image from database in my site but it does not want.

I have such result:[My web-site](http://pixs.ru/uploaded/Bezimyanni_7525409_9556034.png/9556034_3951148/)

I have tried all of the other stackoverflow help topics on here already and none of them are working for me.

I am following the directions in "Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework" by Steven Sanderson (pages 256-262) and it is just not working.

My class:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product product, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                product.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                product.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(product.ImageData,0,image.ContentLength);
            }
            repository.SaveProduct(product);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", product.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }      
            return View(product);    
    }
```

My action method:

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int productId)
    {
        Product prod = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
        if (prod != null)
        {
            return File(prod.ImageData, prod.ImageMimeType);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And my view:

View:

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Domain.Entities.Product

@using(Html.BeginForm("Edit","Admin",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{

  @Html.EditorForModel()

    <div class="editor-label">Image</div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @if (Model.ImageData == null)
    {
        @:None 
    }
    else
    {
        <img width="150" height="150" scr="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product", new {Model.ProductID })"/>
    }
      <div>Upload new image: <input type="file" name="Image" /></div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="save"/>
@Html.ActionLink("Cancle and return to List","Index")
```

}

Comment: `GetImage` returns a `File` not the url for a file. `src` accepts a URL for a file.

Comment: @Liam: as the source of the image should be the result of a call to action method GetImage

Comment: First, you have the attribute `scr` instead of `src`.  Second, you're trying to put a binary file where a URL is expected in your view, like Liam said.

Comment: @Amy OMG,I must be more attentive.I changed scr to src and it's working now.Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh, cool.  I'll submit that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

You have the attribute `scr` instead of `src`.